# Alternative proof for multiplicativity of resultant?

Tags: matrices, polynomials, determinant, resultant

The formula $R(fg,h)=R(f,h)R(g,h)$ follows easily if you express each resultant in terms of the roots of the polynomials involved. It can also be obtained by relating $R(f,h)$ to the determinant of multiplication by $f$ on the space $K[x]/(h)$. But is there a  way to prove the above  formula by extending the three Sylvester matrices involved by cleverly chosen blocks  so that the determinants don't change, the three matrices become square matrices of equal size, and one matrix is the product of the other two?

Comment: I remember seeing a proof that writes $R(f,g)$ and $R(f,h)$ as determinants of block matrices and multiplies them to obtain the Sylvester matrix of $(f,gh)$. Unfortunately I cannto find this proof right now. In the worst case, it was in Apéry's *Elimination* book, which doesn't seem to have found its way on the internet...